# AngularJS: Realizing a multi-page, multi-controller modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a way to realize a modal, that contains a dialog that spans multiple pages. Each page should have its own controller and should make its own server calls for data. An example would be a modal that lets you select a certain day: On the first page, you would select a year, on the second a month and on the third day, narrowing your selection down with every page. But the Url should stay the same for every page.

My first idea was to build something like UI-Router, that lets you define states in which the modal can exist, each state with its own controller and resolve functions:

```
ModalService.register({
    name: "daySelector",
    states: {
        years: {
            templateUrl: "day-selector-years.tpl.html",
            controller: "DaySelectorYearsController",
            params: [],
            resolve: {
                years: function () {
                    return DataService.getYears();
                }
            }
        },
        months: {
            templateUrl: "day-selector-months.tpl.html",
            controller: "DaySelectorMonthsController",
            params: ["year"],
            resolve: {
                months: function (year) {
                    return DataService.getMonthOfYear(year);
                }
            }
        },
        days: {
            templateUrl: "day-selector-days.tpl.html",
            controller: "DaySelectorDaysController",
            params: ["year", "month"],
            resolve: {
                days: function (year, month) {
                    return DataService.getDaysOfMonth(year, month);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

As far as I can tell, this would however require me to do all the compiling and dependency injection by my self. I also have to somehow link the modal to a certain module and a certain scope, to make sure all dependencies can be resolved. Right now, I'm still very unfamiliar with all these rather low-level operations of AngularJS. So before I dive into all of this, I wanted to check if this is really the way to go, or if there is a better approach to solve this problem.

Comment: I too would like to know if there is a better way to solving this problem. According to [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/944) ui-router cannot be used with ui.bootstrap.modals.